# Running a Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a Silverlight Application (3.0) that I have made changes to in Visual Studio and I can debug the application just fine.  My question is what are the steps in getting the application to run through IIS?  Visual Studio's project folder for my app is called SilverlightApplication and within that folder it has another SilverlightApplication folder and a folder called SilverlightApplication.Web  I assume I copy of of these to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot.  Any additional steps?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to register the MIME types, if not registered already.

The following link contains info on that: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/

The second step is to copy the clientaccesspolicy.xml to the wwwroot, if you have one. 
This file is only necessary for cross domain calls, what does not appear to be your case.
After that you can just deploy the app just like any other ASP.NET app.

Comment: Hi Klinger- I added .xaml to the MIME types as your first link talked about. I then added the clientaccesspolicy to the wwwroot folder. Last I copied the SilverlightApplication2 folder (that contained the .xaml files and cs, etc) to the wwwroot folder. I then tried to hit http://localhost/SilverlightApplication2 in the browser and I get a http 403 forbidden error. Did I miss a step?

Comment: I then tried to hit http://localhost/silverlightapplication2/MainPage.xaml and got the below error

Startup URI: http://localhost/SilverlightApplication2/MainPage.xaml
Application Identity: 

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Class' attribute does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' namespace. Line '1' Position '14'.
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParser.ThrowExceptionWithLine(String message, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 linePosition)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlParser.ThrowException(

Comment: You can develop a Silverlight app in more than one way, as per your message your app uses Xaml+c#, that means that you have a compilation process and in this case the output of that is a xap file. This kind of app by default generates a ClientBin folder where the xap file is located. For this kind of app you just need to deploy the content of the Web project. The ClientBin folder is within this project. To run the app you have to reach the page that contains the Silverlight object tag, usually Default.aspx/html. Something like: localhost/silverlightapplication2/Default.aspx